# The Changes you requested were not Successful (Error 3022)

Tags: ms-access

I'm currently looking for assistance with this particular issue where for some reason, I keep getting this error:

[image]

Let me explain what I'm trying to accomplish. Right now I have a Main form that has a sub form inside it. This subform allows me to input information in it to be saved on the corresponding data-table. there are multiple subforms for the user to fill out, hence why the main form exists to keep every tidy. When the user finishes entering in the data into the subform, they click a button that has the following VB code:

```
Private Sub cmdSave2_Click()
Me!PatientInfo.SetFocus
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec
End Sub
```

Which allows the user to go to the next record and input more data. I did some digging and read information that the issue may be that the ID data type settings aren't configured to prevent duplicating the Autonumber increment number, however:

[image]

Everything is set up correctly. So I'm not sure what's causing this error to occur. There's also no relationships between the tables either. If anyone could possibly help me, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: The message clearly says same value is being entered into primary or indexed field. If you user `AutoNumer` data type then user no need to enter any value to that field. Else check user data what they are entering. If you maintain any unique string then you can use some vba code to make/generate unique string so that they do not generate duplicate value for primary key field.

Comment: The problem however is there's no way for a user to enter a value in that field, so theres no way a duplication issue can occur. I checked all the control sources and they're for differen't fields.

Comment: Really sounds like a design issue, not programming and therefore question not appropriate for SO. Are queries used for each form RecordSource? Maybe simplify so bound to tables. Not necessarily issue with autonumber, could be some other index, maybe a compound index that is duplicated.

Comment: Check Allen Browne's site on [fixing autonumber fields with the wrong seed](http://allenbrowne.com/ser-40.html). It's certainly possible your autonumber field has an incorrect seed, and that would cause this issue. Also, check his part about badly designed forms with subforms, it sounds like you might be doing exactly what he explained there.